# How to implement IDisposable properly

Tags: c#, idisposable

I've seen so much C# code in my time as a developer that attempt to help the GC along by setting variables to null or calling Dispose() on classes (DataSet for example) within thier own classes Dispose() method that 
I've been wondering if there's any need to implement it in a managed environment.

Is this code a waste of time in its design pattern?

```
class MyClass : IDisposable 
{
    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        otherVariable = null;
        if (dataSet != null)
        {
            dataSet.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The GC *does not* call `.Dispose()` (It does, however, call the finalize `~MyClass()` method, which you can provide a call to the `Dispose()` method to have resources automatically managed when the GC decides to clean up your class).

You must always provide a way of disposing internal resources such as `DataSets` to code that uses your classes (and ensure you actually call `.Dispose()` or wrap the constructor in a `using`). Using `IDisposable` on your classes that use internal resources is highly recommended.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx):

> The primary use of this interface is
>   to release unmanaged resources. The
>   garbage collector automatically
>   releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no
>   longer used. However, it is not
>   possible to predict when garbage
>   collection will occur. Furthermore,
>   the garbage collector has no knowledge
>   of unmanaged resources such as window
>   handles, or open files and streams.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    otherVariable = null;
    if (dataSet != null)
    {
        dataSet.Dispose();
        dataSet = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, Dispose methods are not a waste of time.

The dispose pattern is there to allow a caller to clean up a class as soon as they have finished with it, rather than waiting for the GC to collect it. The delay doesn't matter much for plain heap memory, which is why basic classes like `String` don't implement it. What Dispose is useful for however is cleaning up **unmanaged** resources. Somewhere internally, the Dataset class is using an unmanaged resource, so it provides a dispose method to allow you to let it know when that unmanaged resource can be released.

If the pattern has been followed correctly Dataset will also have a finalizer (or some subclass will) which means that if you didn't dispose of it manually, eventually the GC would run, the finalizer would get called and the unmanaged resource would be cleaned up that way. This unmanaged resource might be important though, imagine if it was a file lock, or a database connection, you don't really want to hang around waiting for the GC to run before you can reuse your database connection. **Dispose provides a deterministic way of cleaning up resources when they are finished rather than relying on the non-deterministic GC.**

As for setting variables to null in a dispose method. It nearly all cases it would be pointless. setting a variable to null removes a reference to that variable, which will make it eligible for garbage collection (if that's the last reference), but as you are disposing of the class anyway, you are likely to be going out of scope for the containing class so the internal class will become eligible for collection anyway.

If you have member variables inside your class that are disposable that you created (not just references you hold), then you should always call dispose on them from your own class's dispose method, but don't bother setting them to null.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely. If you have member variables which are disposable, then you probably should dispose of it like that. Your object may live longer than the scope of the work it is doing as the garbage collector is not guaranteed to run at any particular time.

Setting managed variables to null is a waste of time though. The object won't get GC'd any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage truck comes to my area every week but it doesn't collect my garbage unless I put my garbage bin in a way that it can collect.

You should simply remove all unwanted event subscriptions, reference and clear unmanaged handlers. Then Garbage Collector will take care of the rest.

Below example show the general best practice to implement IDisposable interface. Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class DisposeExample
{
    // A base class that implements IDisposable. 
    // By implementing IDisposable, you are announcing that 
    // instances of this type allocate scarce resources. 
    public class MyResource: IDisposable
    {
        // Pointer to an external unmanaged resource. 
        private IntPtr handle;
        // Other managed resource this class uses. 
        private Component component = new Component();
        // Track whether Dispose has been called. 
        private bool disposed = false;

        // The class constructor. 
        public MyResource(IntPtr handle)
        {
            this.handle = handle;
        }

        // Implement IDisposable. 
        // Do not make this method virtual. 
        // A derived class should not be able to override this method. 
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method. 
            // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to 
            // take this object off the finalization queue 
            // and prevent finalization code for this object 
            // from executing a second time.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios. 
        // If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly 
        // or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources 
        // can be disposed. 
        // If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the 
        // runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference 
        // other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed. 
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Check to see if Dispose has already been called. 
            if(!this.disposed)
            {
                // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed 
                // and unmanaged resources. 
                if(disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose managed resources.
                    component.Dispose();
                }

                // Call the appropriate methods to clean up 
                // unmanaged resources here. 
                // If disposing is false, 
                // only the following code is executed.
                CloseHandle(handle);
                handle = IntPtr.Zero;

                // Note disposing has been done.
                disposed = true;

            }
        }

        // Use interop to call the method necessary 
        // to clean up the unmanaged resource.
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        // Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code. 
        // This destructor will run only if the Dispose method 
        // does not get called. 
        // It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize. 
        // Do not provide destructors in types derived from this class.
        ~MyResource()
        {
            // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here. 
            // Calling Dispose(false) is optimal in terms of 
            // readability and maintainability.
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Insert code here to create 
        // and use the MyResource object.
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of `IDisposable` isn't to destroy resources--it's to *release* them.  When a `FileStream` opens a file, it requests that the OS prevent anyone else from using the file until further notice; calling `Dispose` on the `FileStream` doesn't destroy the file--to the contrary, it *makes it usable by other entities*.  The GC operates on the principle that there should be no rush to destroy things when there's space to hold them, but once code has no more use for a `FileStream`, it should try to make the file available again to other code as soon as possible.

Comment: @supercat: Not quite sure what you are trying to say. I guess FileStream Dispose does release the file handler and let the garbage collector to clear managed instances. It's sole purpose if not to make it usable for others.If you don't open the file exclusively, it may be able to use by others anyway.

Comment: The reason GC alone isn't sufficient for things like `FileStream` isn't that they *always* holds a file lock in a fashion that interferes with other entities that need to use the file, but that they *sometimes* do, and it's generally easier to release resources when they're no longer needed, without regard for whether contention would actually exist, than to identify cases where contention won't exist and abandon resources without releasing them in such cases.  Note that the *sometimes* doesn't have to be very "often" to make `IDisposable` worthwhile.  Even if abandoning a file stream...

Comment: ...would work 99% of the time, it may be easier to have code call `Dispose` on file streams 100% of the time when they are no longer needed than to make code which generally doesn't dispose of them work 100% of the time.